# Oracle Java 1.7 Broke the Xcode Application, how to uncheck?

Tags: java, xcode, macos

Someone stated in an older thread that you can do 2 things to fix this issue:

*Uninstall Java 1.7 and fallback to Apple Java 1.6.34 or 35 work or
temporarily turn off Java 1.7. Goto: Applications > Utilities > Java Preferences and un-check java 1.7. After that the uploader worked. If you need 1.7 you can turn it back on after you upload.*

I can not use the first option, since I need the Java JRE for other development tasks

How do you uncheck it then? I can not seem to find Java Preferences under Utilities. I have a Java option in the settings options under "Other", where I can get to Java runtime environment settings. Here I have a line for the Java 1.7 and a check in enabled, but I cannot seem to uncheck it. Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was never resolved. 
Apple helped with the project, and confirmed there was a bug in their validation code. For submitting I had to use an IPA and Application loader.